# place 3 figures in a row in two column format

Tags: floats

Hi i am usng two column format and i want to place three figures i a row like this figure and every figure should have separate caption
[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{makecell}%
    %table
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{times}
    %\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{algorithm} 
    %\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
     \usepackage{algorithmic}
    
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
    \makeatother
    
    %\documentclass{IEEEtran}
    
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
        
    \begin{document}
     \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig9.PNG}}
      \caption{ssssssss}
      \label{Fig9}
    \end{minipage}\hfill % maximize horizontal separation
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig10.PNG}}
      \caption{vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv}
      \label{Fig10}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

i also tried this code but it didnt place figures equal in size

```
\begin{figure*}

\floatsetup{floatrowsep=Qquad}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{bbbbb}\label{bbb}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{aaa.png}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{bbb}\label{Hedgehog}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{aaa.png}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{cccc}\label{Ernst}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{aaa.png}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: And the "triple figure" should be within a single column, or span both columns?

Comment: span both column like a sample figure in question

Comment: I would just use the `subcaption` package and subfigures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in LaTeX that forbids you to place multiple `\caption`s in a single `figure` or `figure*` environment.

You can nest `minipage`s inside your float to get the correct width for your captions.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\usepackage{duckuments} % <- dummy content

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \caption{This is a duck}%
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \caption{This is another duck}%
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \caption{But then the ducks arrived}%
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure*}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: huh. you bet mi for 30 seconds :-) +1

Comment: thankyou i need to place caption for every  figure.. but this code is not printing it saying package floatrow eroor. caption lost

Comment: @user12 then don't use `floatrow`, my document body works for your preamble you posted in your question (yes, I've tested it).

Comment: yeah error was on my side thats why i asked :) thanks